# how to prevent session abandonment for idle user (session wise)

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a page on my web app where users might use for potentially hours with no server interaction. all interactions are done on the page with javascript.

how can I prevent a session abandonment if I do want to have it set for 20 minutes on all other pages?

my solution is sending an empty ajax call every 10 minutes just to tickle the server, but is there any other option?

Comment: *sending an empty ajax call every 10 minutes* is a good option indeed.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't read that you was making an ajax call. As you can see from my answer, yes, that's the right thing to do. You can only optimize it, by making a very simple page or web service that does the possible minimun.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dummy ajax call to renew the session timeout.

To do this, create an empty .aspx page, and use whatever you want to load that page to renew the session. For example, a JavaScript `setInterval` and a jquery `$.get()`

If you don't fill comfortable using JavaScript and jQuery, you always can use an Ajax `Timer' and another Ajax`UpdatePanel`.

This guarantees that the session will keep alive while the browser is open.

Making all sessions longer doesn't look like the best possible solution.

Dependign on where you need this functionality, you can implement it on a master page, or include it where needed. You can even include it in the masterpage and enable or disable the timer.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net, you can change Session.Timeout before returning to extend it on that page.  I have not tested whether or not it would un-extend on other subsequent requests, but it would be worth looking at.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319(v=vs.90).aspx